# is it possible assign 2 paths for one user defined environment variable?

Tags: java, variables, path, classpath, environment-variables

Is it possible to assign multiple paths to one environment variable? Example like `JAVE_HOME= C:/Java/jdk1.6/bin, C:/jdk1.5/bin`. I have two projects; one is working on java 1.5 version another 1.6, when set path like above it not recognizing? Any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0):

you can create two batch files (batch1_5.cmd  and batch1_6.cmd)

batch1_6.cmd

```
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.6
SET PATH=C:\Java\jdk1.6\bin;%PATH%
```

batch1_5.cmd

```
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\jdk1.5
SET PATH=C:\jdk1.5\bin;%PATH%
```

run  the specific file to set corresponding java version

(or)

if you are using eclipse then you can create project specific settings

[image]

Comment: Hi upog , i refereed  java version as an example, my requirement is custom variable.

Comment: for custom variable also i guess you need to have two different batch file to set two different values

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that somewhere in a config file you'll be able to set the environment variable that the project follows.

As far as I know, there is no way to have one environment variable point to two locations.